# How to find (or buy) template projects

Tags: android, templates

I'm interested in setting up a football league app. I'm quite sure there are already app like this done somewhere. Where can i find them (source code)? or buy them? Is there a website selling it? so i can just modify the features.

Comment: you can find/buy source codes on https://codecanyon.net

Answer (score 0):

you can find and buy project from this sites :

https://themeforest.net/search/android

https://codecanyon.net/search/android?utf8=%E2%9C%93